# Python script returns NoneType

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, arcfm

When I run the below script, it returns: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'" for line 14 (starting with fcListPoint).

What is NoneType?

I have permissions to access the database. When I tried the ListFeatureClass() function in the .sde environment, it did not return anything, but when I ran it in my default gdb, it returned fc's there.

```
import arcpy

# Set the workspace to the geodatabase that contains the feature classes
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\DatabaseConnections\DC_GISPROD_SDE_USER.sde'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# define the feature classes that the rows that contain null values will be inserted into.
# nullPntFc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outPolyPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Get the list of feature classes in the geodatabase
fcListLine = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Section", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet")
print (fcListLine)
fcListPoint = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Transformer", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Bank", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Location", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet")
```

Comment: If you're getting an error on line 14, you don't need to include anything after line 16. All that's needed is a reproducible code snippet, not the whole shebang. You should probably test for `None` rather than assuming that the list function will return data.

Comment: Good point, just edited the post now. I tested for ```None``` and it returned true.

Comment: NoneType is a foundational type in Python and is represented solely by `None`.  Before diving too much deeper into ArcPy, it might be beneficial to deepen your understanding of Python itself.

Comment: Instead of doing list math all on one line, I'd conditionally `list.append()` with non-null return values.  What you need to review (and that we can't help with) is whether the returned lists are correct or there's some other data problem (case dependency?? other??)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, this is mostly a *Python* thing, not an ArcGIS/arcpy thing.

This code/error seems to illustrate your situation

```
>>> [1,2,3] + None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

There are a few ways to protect against this, and they all involve checking if a list is None. The easiest, most readable code would be to break your 3 `ListFeatureClasses` into their own lines and test.
However, you should be able to get away with a big single line of code where you an use an `or` statement. If the `ListFeatureClass` evaluates to `None`, then `or` will kick in and use the provided value, in this case I use, an empty list. You can add an empty list to an existing list.

`fcListPoint = (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Transformer", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") or []) + (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Bank", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") or []) + (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Location", feature_dataset = "ARCFM.ElectricDataSet") or [])`

Or for readability/example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [3,4,5]
>>> c = None
>>> fclist = (a or []) + (b or []) + (c or [])
>>> fclist
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```